# C++ standard library constants for big and small numbers?

Tags: c++, standard-library

Is there a constant in the C++ std lib somewhere that means something like "largest representable number" and "smallest representable number"? In Matlab, we have things like `EPS`, `realmax`, and `realmin`. I was wondering if there was an equivalent for C++.

Comment: What do you mean by number? Integers? Reals? Something else entirely?

Comment: Any basic type. I left it intentionally open.

Comment: Be careful when using an idea like "epsilon" and make sure you really understand what it means and how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the limits header you can find a templatized function for max and min,

```
std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max();
std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min();
```

Here is some reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find the modern way:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Answer (score 0):

Sure, look in limits.h for INT_MAX etc.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/

Look in float.h for DBL_MAX etc. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/